# SwiftUI + Firebase - Views are inconsistent

Tags: firebase, swiftui, tabview

I'm using Firebase for my app. I have 2 tabs.

In the first tab, I'm fetching data from my view model and everything works just fine. In my second view, I'm fetching from the same view model.

When I load the app, it starts on the first tab. Everything looks good. When I switch to the second tab, everything looks good. However, when I switch back to the first tab then to the second tab again, the data fetch doesn't work in the second tab only. Please help!

In trying to debug, I put print statements in the `fetchData` function in the view model. When I open the first tab, it calls the function once. When I open the second tab, it calls it twice.

Here's my view model:

```swift
  class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var routines = [Routine]()

    func fetchData() {
      print("ViewModel func")

      Firestore.firestore().collection("routines").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
          print("No documents")
          return
        }
        self.routines = documents.map { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Routine in
          let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
          let uid = data["uid"] as? String ?? ""
          let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""

          return Routine(id: .init(), uid: uid, name: name)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's the tab view that directs to 2 different tabs

```swift
  TabView(selection: $selection) {
    TodayView()
      .tabItem {
        Image(systemName: "sun.dust")
        Text("Today")
      }
      .tag(1)
    HomeView()
      .tabItem {
      Image(systemName: "arrow.2.circlepath")
      Text("My Routines")
    }
    .tag(2)
  }
```

Comment: It looks like the issue is not in the provided code.

Comment: You have not shared the code for where you are creating and assigning the view model to both views.

Comment: Hi @David, I think you need to provide more context. Can you please provide the essential code for `TodayView` and `HomeView`, so we can see how the `ViewModel` is being used? Also, please keep in mind that in `fetchData`, you create a snapshot listener. This listener will stay active until you remove it (using the `ListenerRegistration` it returns).